# Can I set x to 0 for all selected pixels?

Tags: vertices

I have a flat model pictured below but each vertex is slightly off from 0. Is there some way to select all vertices and set them to exactly 0? If I select them all and set x to 0 it just makes the median 0 but individual verts are slightly greater or less. I would have to select all individually and set to 0 one by one. Is there a fast way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Pick a single point, and make sure it's at X-0 by using the Transform Menu (N). Then change the _transform pivot point_ (center top of the viewport, to the left of the magnet) to _active element_. Then select all the vertices, making sure the one you zero'd out is the active one (last one selected). Then scale them all on the X to 0 - this will place them all at the same (0) X location as the active one.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett No need to make it complicated with pivot points: select all, then `S`, `X`, `0` to scale them to be flat on X, then you can set them to 0 afterwards because their median is now the same as all their X values.

Comment: thank you both! They probably both work but I like the second answer as its simpler and I have to do this all the time. Hard to remember all the tricks to make blender do simple thing. The less I need to overload my poor tired brain the better. @gordon if you post it as an answer I will accept that one. Thanks to both of you again!